# Calculating duration for traveling to international countries

Tags: timezone

I want to calculate the allowance for a consultant traveling to overseas countries. 
I have to take into account that I can gain a day or lose a day traveling to an international country. Different countries has a different set of allowances.

How can I adjust my code to know whether I will gain a day or lose and adjust in my calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the dates/times using the local timezone information.  Convert from that timezone to UTC for both dates/times and calculate the difference between the two based on UTC.

For example:

Left: 11/11/2008 10AM CST (Chicago) == 11/11/2008 4PM UTC (-6)

Arrived: 11/12/2008 5AM CET (Copenhagen) == 11/12/2008 4AM UTC (+1)

Difference = 12 hours